# Squid and more hosts

Tags: iptables, squid

I configurated my Squid as tranasparent cache on a visible_host myhost.com

Now I need to make a test:
- I modified my hosts file to redirect browser request myHost2.com to
the same machine (squid + apache)
 But when I try I see this message error:

```
The requested URL could not be retrieved

________________________________

While trying to retrieve the URL: http://myhost2.com/

The following error was encountered:

Unable to determine IP address from host name for myhost2.com

The dnsserver returned:

Name Error: The domain name does not exist.

This means that:

 The cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL.
 Check if the address is correct.

Your cache administrator is root.
```

How can I allow this request? This is only a test so I would to pass
the request to my apache. Squid not has to filter the request..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that Squid is unable to resolve the hostname.

Squid needs to be resolve DNS names for any system it is proxying for.  This may mean you need to modify the hosts file on your Squid host, or it may mean setting up a local DNS server on the Squid host.